# CreateFile dwDesiredAccess and dwShareMode combinations

Tags: c++, winapi, file-io

I'm trying to implement a `checkAccess()` method on Windows in C++ and want to use `CreateFile()` method. Access modes are existence, read and write. For these 3 following are the `dwDesiredAccess` and `dwShareMode` combinations I'm proposing to use:

```
mode          dwDesiredAccess          dwShareMode
existence:         0            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE
read         GENERIC_READ       FILE_SHARE_READ
write        GENERIC_WRITE      FILE_SHARE_WRITE
```

Are these combinations accurate?

While testing combinations I noticed that if I call

```
CreateFile(file,
           GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
           FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
           NULL,
           OPEN_EXISTING,
           FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
           NULL)
```

on a file and call the same method on the same file again but I only pass `GENERIC_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_READ` the second call fails. Why is the second call failing? Documentation says modes that cannot conflict. The second call is a subset of the first call so there's no conflict.

The call fails with error 32: `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`.

Comment: In the second call if I say `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE` the call passes.

Comment: Did you call `GetLastError` when the call to `CreateFile` failed like the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) says? If so what was the error? If not, that would be something to try, then [edit] the result into your question.

Comment: The extra indirection in the share mode gets every programmer confused, it is like using pointers.  When you use FILE_SHARE_READ then you implicitly say that other programs are not allowed to write to the file.   Well, that's aiming a bit high.  It is quite common that a program writes a log file and only *appends* text.  And will use FILE_SHARE_READ to say that it is just fine when another program reads the log data.  That program has GENERIC_WRITE access, you say you don't like that.   Are you sure?  Denying writing is appropriate on a random access file, not so much on a text stream.

Comment: @HansPassant so the second call is failing because it's requesting exclusive read access?

Comment: It is the standard mistake, you should know better than me whether it applies to your specific case.  The acid test is opening the file with Notepad.  If it can do it then so can you, it uses GENERIC_READ and FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE.

Comment: The second call failed, because the file is already opened with write access, and you are denying write access by specifying read sharing only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these combinations accurate?

I would probably use these instead:

```
mode          dwDesiredAccess    dwShareMode
--------------------------------------------
existence:    0                  FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE
read          GENERIC_READ       FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE
write         GENERIC_WRITE      FILE_SHARE_READ
```

Checking for existence should allow other processes to open the file with any access.

Opening a file for read-only access should not prevent other processes from opening the same file for writing.

Opening a file for write-only access should prevent other processes from opening the same file for writing.  You don't want them overwriting each other at the same time.  But you should allow other processes to read what is being written.

Think of apps that need to read/write live data, such as log generators and log viewers.

And BTW, your `existence` check would be better implemented using `FindFirstFile()` or `GetFileAttributes/Ex()` instead, so that you can query metadata about the file (which would fail if the file does not exist) without having to actually open the file itself, thus the sharing rights would be irrelevant.  If you choose to use `CreateFile()` for the `existence` check, make sure you don't treat `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` as an error, since it is implicitly telling you that the file *does* exist, you just can't open it.

> Why is the second call failing?

Because the second call is only granting read sharing, which means other handles to the same file are allowed to have the file open for reading but not for writing, however the first handle is already open for writing, thus the second call cannot be satisfied and fails.

> The second call is a subset of the first call so there's no conflict.

Yes, there is a conflict.

Comment: Can I say that this is a strange behaviour? Why not just `CreateFile(GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ);` Then `CreateFile(GENERIC_READ,NO_SHARE_MODE_REQUIRED_TO_ACCESS_A_FILE_THAT_WAS_ALREADY_OPENED_TO_BE_SHARED)`? Is this some kind of security reason?

Comment: @user13947194 not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: Mr. Remy I am afraid that I am unable to reword my comment in a manner I am sure you would understand. If you could point out section(s) of my comment you don't understand I might be able to clarify.